# using (not in) in inner join sql

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, inner-join, notin

i have two tables

> 1) tbluser 2) userlogin

tbluser consist of

> username and email

and userlogin looks like

```
create table userlogin
(
username varchar(50),
[date] datetime
)
```

i want to select email from tbluser and validate userlogin(table 2)

i want email of the employees from table 1 which are not in table 2 with selected date range

so i created a procedure

```
alter proc TMSautomail
@datefrm datetime,
@dateto datetime
as
begin
SELECT
     tblUser.Email
from
     tblUser
         inner join
     userlogin
         on
      tblUser.UserName not in userlogin.username
where userlogin.date between @datefrm and @dateto
end
```

it is showing me error,
when i change the procedure
to this

```
alter proc TMSautomail
@datefrm datetime,
@dateto datetime
as
begin
SELECT
     tblUser.Email
from
     tblUser
         left outer join
     userlogin
         on
      tblUser.UserName = userlogin.username
where userlogin.date between @datefrm and @dateto and userlogin.username is null
end
```

the procedure returns blank column,

i want to fetch email of table one and validate with username which are not in table 2,

my second table is consist of one entry

it should return all rows of table one

Comment: There's no need for join, only NOT IN and a subquery.

Comment: i used that also but when i add where clause it is showing all rows

Comment: Do show that query also

Comment: ok subquery is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` and a sub-query:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE TMSautomail(
    @datefrm datetime,
    @dateto datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT u.Email
    FROM tblUser u
    WHERE u.Email NOT IN (
        SELECT Email
        FROM tblUser u1
            INNER JOIN UserLogin l
                ON u1.Username = l.Username
        WHERE l.Date BETWEEN @datefrm AND @dateto
    )

END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT u.Email
    FROM tblUser u
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Email
        FROM  UserLogin l
                WHERE u1.Username = l.Username
        AND l.Date BETWEEN @datefrm AND @dateto
    )
```